# google cloud storage curl php upload

Tags: php, curl, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload  a file to google cloud storage using Curl php.

```
define("BASE","https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/");
$key='XXXXX';
$authheaders = array(
"Authorization: Bearer " .$key,
"Content-Type: image/jpeg"
);

$bucket='gs://storage-8c79a.appspot.com';

$file='1234';
$fileName='1.pdf';
$url=BASE.$bucket.'/o?name=name_of_file.jpg&uploadType=multipart';
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $authheaders);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "HTTP/1.1.5");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
// 1 is CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1, which is not always defined in PHP.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);


$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo $response;
```

Output:

> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found X-GUploader-UploadID: AEnB2UriDzXPtSs2Gac2BVfR4b4abfkroNy5gBCg8D85az3MK69YubPCCp_k3cx64A2MsSCMu-N_4F-RfFe10Vh_GjUbrjkrkzZ4NJ3Tlry4I8js-pgUqtw Vary: Origin Vary: X-Origin Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 9 Date: Tue, 23 Aug 2016 09:57:23 GMT Server: UploadServer Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34,33,32,31,30" Not Found

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Explain your root problem, be more specific to this.

Comment: I have edited your question to make it a bit more readable. On this site, users are encouraged to [edit] and re-edit questions to improve them as much as possible, so please do read through the guidance at [ask] and come back to review your question.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
define("BASE","https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/");
$bucket='gs://someproject.appspot.com';
$url=BASE.$bucket.'/o?name=name_of_file.jpg;
```

leads to a URL like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/gs://someproject.appspot.com/o?name=name_of_file.jppg
```

The bucket name section of the URL should be just "someproject.appspot.com". Remove the "gs://".

Comment: You also aren't properly using `uploadType=multipart`, but rather `uploadType=media` for a raw upload. I notice that the `Content-Type: image/jpeg` disagrees with the unused `$fileName='1.pdf';` but in both cases, this looks like you're just uploading content rather than content plus metadata. See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload for more information on the different upload options.